# why does it take priority

Tags: html, css

For context for this question, I am building [this](http://peresola.com/Projects/KyivEvents/index.html) website.

I've noticed that, in `width` less than 700px, the arrow overlaps the hidden text behind. Therefore, it is not clickable. But I discovered that `.post p { margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;}` is taking priority over `.descr  {margin-top:30px;text-align:justify;}` when screen is less than 700 px. Why is that? I thought that the more detailed (`.descr`, which is a `class`, is more detailed than `p`) would take priority. It is not the case because in chrome tool developpers `margin-top:30px;` shows as crossed. Is it because there are actually 4 `p` under div `.post`?

Comment: In addition to the good links provided in both the answers, here is the w3c spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.class p` is more specific that `.class` ('specificity' or 'more specific' is what we call priority in css)

Each selector in css has a defined level of specificity.

`#ID` is more specific than `.class`

and `.class` is more specific than a html element, such as `p`

However, specificity also stacks, so chaining selectors will increase the specificity accordingly. Therefore, a class followed by another selector will over-ride a class applied to that selector. Even though `p` is less specific it is still added onto the specificity of `.class`

[This calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) will help you and [this article](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/) goes into more detail

Comment: Thanks, Toni! I marked your as best answer because you took the time to explain a rookie like me what's all about specificity. Thank you. Calculator is handy as well, yay!

Comment: @perettxintxola knowing the right word can make all the difference!

Answer (score 3):

The <strike>priority</strike> specificity is determined for the entire selector and is a combination of all the parts in it. So `.post p` is '1 class plus 1 tag' which has a higher specificity than `.descr`, which is just '1 class'.

See also [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: thank you! specificity is THE word, I was not googling it right, that's why I could not find anything. Crystal clear now!